# List columns in a table with associated values for one record

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am building a query which should list all columns in a table along with a data sample for each column name.  For example, if I had a table called 'person' with the columns of 'first', 'last' and 'age', I would need it listed like this:

```
table_name    column_name    column_value
person        person_id      443
person        first          john
person        last           smith
person        age            48
```

The goal of this query is to actually list all columns in any given table - I have this working.  I want to have a data value listed in the third column (column_value) so I can check the front end of applications against the backend and ensure I am actually dealing with the correct column.

This table may have hundreds or thousands of records, but I am just trying to pull one matching record.  The average table columns I am working with in any given table is 200+, so I can't do this by hand.

Here is the query I am using to pull all columns from a table:

```
SELECT table_name
       , COLUMN_NAME
       , '' AS column_value
FROM   information_schema.COLUMNS
WHERE  TABLE_NAME LIKE '%person%'
ORDER BY TABLE_NAME
```

This query returns the following results (notice column_value is empty):

```
table_name    column_name    column_value
person        person_id
person        first
person        last
person        age
```

I will use the unique primary key to identify a single person record to pull from - this will ensure I don't have repeated column names (ex. person_id/first/last/age repeating for each time a person is pulled.)

The question is, how do I turn this into a list of columns along with the value of a specific selected record in the 'column_value' column??

### UPDATE

Just to clarify, I am basically trying to turn this type of query & output:

```
SELECT * FROM person WHERE person_id = 443;

** outputs this:
person_id    first    last    age
443          john     smith   48
```

Into this:

```
table_name    column_name    column_value
person        person_id      443
person        first          john
person        last           smith
person        age            48
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this using a database query, rather than at the application level (where this should be trivial)?

Comment: I am sure.  I want to see the exact value of a single record straight from the database.  I don't have a web or application server connected to this system so I can only use queries.  Also, our reporting server is not configured so I can't run an ssrs report.

Comment: If you don't have any applications that connect to this server, then why do you need this very specific and very hard to produce format?  Why isn't the first format you showed (the default) sufficient?

Comment: RBarryYoung: No applications are connected because I am dealing with archived data which needs to be migrated into another system. The first format is sufficient, but I typed it by hand. Read my original post again: I explain that I have many tables with 200+ columns in each. I can't type all of this by hand.

Comment: RBarryYoung: I also don't think this is a very hard to produce format, it's just takes more skill than you and I have. that being said, if you don't know the answer, please don't cloud my post. I did a lot of research on this and posted a well formed question.  Please don't take away from that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this

```
DECLARE @SchemaName sysname
DECLARE @TableName sysname
DECLARE @Colname sysname
DECLARE @SQL_Template nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max)

SET @SchemaName = 'Sales' 
SET @TableName = 'Customer' 

CREATE TABLE ##Results(Colname sysname, colvalue varchar(256))

SET @SQL_Template  = 'INSERT INTO ##Results(Colname,colvalue ) SELECT top 1 ''@Colname '' as Colname,'
                   + ' CONVERT(nvarchar(256),@Colname) AS ColValue'
                   + ' FROM ['+@SchemaName+'].['+@TableName+']'


DECLARE COL_CURSOR CURSOR STATIC FOR
SELECT c.name
FROM  sys.schemas s
 JOIN sys.tables t ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
 JOIN  sys.columns c ON c.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE s.name = 'Sales' AND t.name = 'Customer'
OPEN COL_CURSOR 
FETCH NEXT FROM COL_CURSOR INTO @Colname
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS =0
BEGIN
    SET @SQL = REPLACE(@SQL_Template,'@ColName',@ColName)
    PRINT @SQL
    EXEC sp_executesql  @SQL
FETCH NEXT FROM COL_CURSOR INTO @Colname
END
CLOSE COL_CURSOR 
DEALLOCATE COL_CURSOR 
SELECT * FROM ##Results
DROP TABLE ##Results
```

Comment: This returns the exact format I am looking for, but only one problem: it grabs the first record in the table!  In our system, the first record is partially empty so I can't compare values. I need to be able to select a specific person_id - how would I modify it for this? Otherwise, this query is perfect!

Comment: You'll need a slightly more complicated  value for 
 @SQL_Template

Comment: SET @SQL_Template  = 'INSERT INTO ##Results(Colname,colvalue ) SELECT top 1 ''@Colname '' as Colname,'
                   + ' CONVERT(nvarchar(256),@Colname) AS ColValue'
                   + ' FROM ['+@SchemaName+'].['+@TableName+']'
                   + ' WHERE ['+@KeyColumn+'] = '+@KeyValueString

Comment: And obviously you'll need to declare and initialise KeyColumn and KeyValueString

Answer (score 0):

I have created this procedure which will take Table Name as Parameter and returns the information you have asked for.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_GetTableFormat_And_SampleDate
@TableName NVARCHAR(128)
AS
BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @ColsCasted NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @Cols NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @TableName = t.name
     , @ColsCasted = STUFF(( SELECT ', CAST(' + QUOTENAME(sc.name) + ' AS NVARCHAR(1000)) AS ' + QUOTENAME(sc.name)
                         FROM sys.tables st INNER JOIN sys.columns sc 
                         ON st.object_id = sc.object_id
                         WHERE st.name = @TableName
                         AND st.object_id = t.object_id
                         FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE)
                         .value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1 ,2 ,'')
FROM sys.tables t
WHERE t.name = @TableName
GROUP BY t.name, t.object_id

SELECT @TableName = t.name
     , @Cols = STUFF(( SELECT ', ' + QUOTENAME(sc.name) 
                 FROM sys.tables st INNER JOIN sys.columns sc 
                 ON st.object_id = sc.object_id
                 WHERE st.name = @TableName
                 AND st.object_id = t.object_id
                 FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE)
                 .value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1 ,2 ,'')
FROM sys.tables t
WHERE t.name = @TableName
GROUP BY t.name, t.object_id;

DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @Sql =

N'WITH CTE AS 
 (
 SELECT * FROM (
SELECT TOP 1 ' + @ColsCasted + N'
FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@TableName)  + N') Q 
  UNPIVOT ( VALS for N IN (' + @Cols + '))up
)
SELECT  TableName
      , ColName AS ColumnName
      , VALS AS SampleData 
FROM CTE C INNER JOIN  
(SELECT sc.Name AS ColName, st.Name AS TableName FROM sys.tables st INNER JOIN sys.columns sc 
ON st.object_id = sc.object_id WHERE st.name =  '''+ @TableName +  N''' ) Q2 
ON C.N = Q2.ColName'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @Sql

END
```

**Test**

I have a table called `'Department'` in my database

```
EXECUTE usp_GetTableFormat_And_SampleDate 'Department'
```

**Result Set**

```
╔════════════╦════════════╦════════════╗
║ TableName  ║ ColumnName ║ SampleData ║
╠════════════╬════════════╬════════════╣
║ Department ║ DeptID     ║ 1          ║
║ Department ║ Department ║ HR         ║
╚════════════╩════════════╩════════════╝
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's only a few tables that you have to do then you can bundle it up into a union query along the lines of

```
CREATE PROC sp_person_values (@PersonID  int)
AS 
BEGIN 
    SELECT 'person_id' As ColumnName, CONVERT(varchar(256),person_id) As ColumnValue FROM person WHERE person_id = @PersonID
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'first' As ColumnName, CONVERT(varchar(256),first) As ColumnValue FROM person WHERE person_id = @PersonID
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'last' As ColumnName, CONVERT(varchar(256),last) As ColumnValue FROM person WHERE person_id = @PersonID
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'age' As ColumnName, CONVERT(varchar(256),age) As ColumnValue FROM person WHERE person_id = @PersonID
END
```

Comment: Thanks for the example. Unfortunately I am dealing with hundreds of columns per table - only about 5 or 6 tables, but this adds up to 1000+ columns so I won't be able to type the union/select [column] statements for each. if it's possible to list the columns dynamically for a specific table, please let me know!